# jquery tooltip throwing error: function not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get custom tooltip over image. but during run time it says "method or property  tooltip not defined"
here is my code

```
<script src="/full/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#content img[title]").tooltip();

    });

</script>

<style type="text/css" >

.tooltip 
    {    
        display:none;
        background:transparent url(Images/blackarrow.png);    
        font-size:12px;    
        height:70px;    
        width:160px;    
        padding:25px;    
        color:#eee;  
    }</style>
</asp:Content>


    <div id="content"> <img alt="" src="Images/help1.png" title="Your help comes here" /></div>
```

Comment: Did you include the plugin in the head section? Seems that not.

Comment: yes i did. I even tried same thing in different project with no master page and getting plugiun locally..still no luck.

Comment: Are you including the plugin after include the JQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to include the plugin directly from the developer, just for test. If works, there is some problem with your code.

I've removed the `[title]` from `<img>`, if you really need it, put it again.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#content img").tooltip();

    });

</script>

<style type="text/css" >

    #tooltip {
    width:160px;
    height:70px;
    background:transparent url(Images/blackarrow.png) #eee;
    z-index: 3000;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    opacity: 0.85;
    font-size:12px;    
    padding:25px;    
    color:#eee;  
    position: absolute;
    }
    #tooltip h3, #tooltip div { margin: 0; }


</style>

<div id="content">
    <img alt="" src="Images/help1.png" title="Your help comes here" />
</div>
```

Comment: I tried giving direct from developer too but still I ll try one more time as given above n update u.

Comment: @NandiniT, Maybe your JQuery has some problem, i've done an update in the answer loading the JQuery from Google Library, try to do this to see what happens.